# Database ERROR QLSTATE[HY000] in cake php

Tags: sql, database, cakephp, phpmyadmin

I am trying to create the new data for our project in cakephp. i am having the following database error.

```
Database Error
```

Error: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'id' doesn't have a default value

Notice: If you want to customize this error message, create app\View\Errors\pdo_error.ctp

it's keep showing the ID doesn't have the default value and we can't make any change to the ID since it's our PK . Any help would be appreciate !!!!

Comment: The Id alredy have auto increment and not Null int in our database. Whenever we tried to create the new file the database error keep popping up. Thankssss

Comment: Can you provide the table schema for the tables involved?